# writing a poi workbook to output stream is generating weird values

Tags: servlets, apache-poi

i am aiming to create an Excel file for the user to download via apache poi.

I have this code in my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {

            // create a workbook , worksheet
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("MySheet");
            CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(1);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue( createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string") );
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

            //write workbook to outputstream
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            wb.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            //offer the user the option of opening or downloading the resulting Excel file
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcel.xls");
```

The problem is that i am getting these weird values:

> `…*MySheetŒ®üÿ » ÌÁ w 
>   dü©ñÒMbP?**+‚€%ÿÁƒ„¡"d,,à?à?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found whats wrong. the HttpServletResponse must first be set before anything else

```
//offer the user the option of opening or downloading the resulting Excel file
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcel.xls");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set cell type for each cell, You can do so using :

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
```

Check api for more cell types [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html).

Or You can use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) for the same.

Comment: This was not the right answer, but helped me out with another problem. Thanks :)