# Problems Downloading a file in java

Tags: java, excel, jsp, export

i am having a problem which i have been looking for over a week trying to get a solution for it, but i can't. I tried many examples and not worked. If someone could assist that would be great.

here's my question.

I am trying to create an interface between java and jsp as follows:

I have a file sitting on a shared folder in my local network. for example:

\myserver\temp\myexcelFile.xls

so, what i want to do is that i have a jsp button in my jsp page when actually you click on the button, i need it to get the file from the server and prompt the user whether to open or save it locally, as if you are downloading the file.

i created a button and when it gets triggered it calles a procedure in my java file which is actually imported in the jsp that does read the file from the shared folder and then prompt the user to save it.

here is the procedure that i have:

```
public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    String fileName = "file://myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls";
    URL url = new URL(fileName);

    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(url.getFile());
        byte[] totalBytes = fileName.getBytes();
        out.write(totalBytes);
    } finally {

        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

so in the jsp when someone presses the button, it calls the procedure as follows:

so according to what i need is that once the button is pressed, it should prompt me to save this file: myExcelFile.xls, so you can choose the local path to where you would like to save.

This is what i want to achieve.

I saw hundreds of examples that does it, and none worked as i need.

The issue that i am having is that when i press the button, it does prompt me to save or open the file, but the file is always corrupt, it always says that the file unreadable, and it prompts for missing styles and so on...

I tried all examples that i can think of or even did a lot of research about it, but none of the examples that i saw helps.

I would like this to be a universal prompt so if i have a pdf or html file i would like it to be able to prompt the correct file for the user to save.

Please advice.

Thanks for everyone who would like to contribute in this.

REgards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238479/writing-a-poi-workbook-to-output-stream-is-generating-weird-values

Answer (score 0):

To get the file from the server through servlet, the following code snippet should help. The trick to handling generic file type is setting the correct MIME type for the file using `response.setContentType()`.

```
public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    String fileName = "//myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls";
    String displayName = "myExcelFile.xls";

    try(
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
       ) {
        // Add logic to detect and change MIME Type
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + displayName + "\"");

        BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int dataSize = 0;
        while((dataSize = buffIn.read(data)) != -1) {
            buffOut.write(data, 0, dataSize);
        }
        buffOut.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle or throw exception
    }
```

Comment: ok, so i tested your example, the first thing i realized that it threw an exception and i saw that it has to do with the file location. Accorinding to the file name, the "file://myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls";
was visible to the server as: "file:/myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls";

Comment: was visible to the server as: "file:/myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls"; so it took out one slash, i tried adding double slashes to the existing too: like this "file:////myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls"; and still didn't work. So i ended up changing the path as: "\\\\myserver\\temp\\myExcelFile.xls". That one worked, no exception was thrown.
and i got a prompt to save the file. But when i tried to open it, it took a few minutes to open, and then it said: cell data too large, and it generated a log file saying: HTML ERROR in Cell data too large :

Comment: and the file is still corrupted. WHen i enter the following in the browser: file://myserver/temp/myExcelFile.xls, it opens up fine.

Comment: Have you tried saving the file and then open it? And how large is the file?